# Standard Grade and Curb Height for ADA Compliant Shower Floor

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, floor, installation

I am managing replacement of a bathtub with a walk in shower for my mother in her condo. The HOA is demanding a shower grade of 1 inch per foot which seems far to steep for a person with disabilities. What is the standard grade and curb height for an ADA compliant shower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.ada.gov/regs2010/2010ADAStandards/2010ADAstandards.htm

> 608.7 Thresholds. Thresholds in roll-in type shower compartments shall be 1/2 inch (13 mm) high maximum in accordance with 303. In transfer type shower compartments, thresholds 1/2 inch (13 mm) high maximum shall be beveled, rounded, or vertical.

Ramps(in general) are permitted to be 1:12 (though it is recommended that they be less steep), but areas that are considered wheelchair turning, transfer, parking etc. are limited to 1:48. Nothing specific to "shower floor grade" is in there, but depending on how it's intended to be used (or intended to be ABLE to be used) you could get the 1:48 limitation applied - it's still perfectly good for drainage (1/4" per foot.) 1:12 is not particularly comfortable for normal folks, and is far more than is required for plumbing drainage.

Comment: Thank you. It seems my rep is too low so I can't even up vote you but I tried.

Comment: Patience. You can always "accept" an answer, but I would not suggest doing so yet - I hardly *need* the points and a better answer may yet be forthcoming (and some folks are more apt to give one to a question without an accepted answer.) Meanwhile, you'll get some rep eventually...just be a little patient.